# How to close all the processes one by one in a program that operates with multiprocessing by means of an 'if' validation found in one of them process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, process, multiprocessing

```py
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread
import speech_recognition as sr

def actions_func(conn1_3,conn2_3):

def capture_cam(conn1, conn1b):

def audio_listening(conn2, conn2b):
    global catch_current_frame
    catch_current_frame = False

    # start dameon thread to handle frame requests:
    Thread(target=handle_catch_current_frame_requests, args=(conn2,), daemon=True).start()
    Thread(target=handle_cam_activate_requests, args=(conn2b,), daemon=True).start()

    while True:
        r = sr.Recognizer()

        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            catch_current_frame = False
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            print("Please say something...")
            audio = r.listen(source)

            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-ES")
                print("You have said: \n " + repr(text))

                #Verifications
                if text.lower() == "capture":
                    catch_current_frame = True
                elif text.lower() == "Close your program":
                    #This is where I need to close processes p1, p2 and p3
                    break
                else:
                    pass

            except Exception as e:
                print("Error : " + str(e))


def main_process(finish_state):
    conn1, conn1_3 = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=True)
    conn2, conn2_3 = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=True)
    conn1b, conn2b = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=True)

    #Process 1
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=capture_cam, args=(conn1, conn1b, ))
    p1.start()
    #Process 2
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=audio_listening, args=(conn2, conn2b, ))
    p2.start()
    #Process 3
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=actions_func, args=(conn1_3 ,conn2_3 ,))
    p3.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    finish_state = multiprocessing.Event()
    main_process(finish_state)

print("continue the code... ")
```

I need that when the variable `text` is equal to `"Close your program"` the 3 active processes(`p1`,`p2`,`p3`) are closed.

I have tried to do something like this:

```py
elif text.lower() == "Close your program":
    print("the process has been interrupted!")
    finish_state.set()
    for process in [p1, p2, p3]:
        process.terminate()
```

But it is not working for me, and I would need a better code that allows me to close them one by one in that code block if `text` is equal to `"Close your program"`.

What should I do so that under that condition all the processes are closed one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* try the following Event-based solution (but there are even simpler solutions to follow):

Have `main_process` pass to `audio_listening` an additional argument, `finish_state`:

```py
def main_process():
    conn1, conn1_3 = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=True)
    conn2, conn2_3 = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=True)
    conn1b, conn2b = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=True)

    #Process 1
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=capture_cam, args=(conn1, conn1b, ))
    p1.start()
    #Process 2
    finish_state = multiprocessing.Event()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=audio_listening, args=(conn2, conn2b, finish_state))
    p2.start()
    #Process 3
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=actions_func, args=(conn1_3 ,conn2_3 ,))
    p3.start()

    finish_state.wait()
    p1.terminate()
    p2.terminate() # Not really necessary since the process is ending by itself
    p3.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_process()
```

Note that it is now `main_process` that is creating the `finish_state` `multiprocessing.Event` instance; there appears to be no need for it to be passed as an argument. When the event is set, the main process will terminate the subprocesses that it has created.

Then in `audio_processing:`

```py
def audio_listening(conn2, conn2b, finish_state):
    ...
                if text.lower() == "capture":
                    catch_current_frame = True
                elif text.lower() == "Close your program":
                    # Set the finish state event:
                    finish_state.set()
                    break
```

There are even two simpler alternatives that do not even require an `Event` variable:

The `audio_process` process is in an infinite loop until it either gets a "Close your program" message or it gets an exception. In both cases it terminates and presumably we then want the other two processes to terminate, also. Therefore, the main process can just issue a call to `p2.join()` after it has started all the other processes in order to wait for the `audio_process` process to complete and then either:

1. Call `p1.terminate()` followed by `p3.terminate()`.
2. Or start processes `p1` and `p3` specifying *daemon=True*, e.g. `p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=capture_cam, args=(conn1, conn1b), daemon=True)`. Being daemon processes they will now automatically terminate as soon as the main process terminates. Therefore, there is no need to call `terminate` on these processes.